# Proper Setup for a simple AWS S3 website using CloudFront & Route, with base domain and www subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudfront

Which is the better design, and why? (see 2 tables)

**1. Here** is the configuration of my working website (example.com is the prevent domain)
as setup via a Youtube Tutorial...

| Route53 | Cloudfront Dist | S3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A record **example.com** --> d1wxyz | **d1wxyz**.cloudfront.net --> 1. | 1. example.com Hosting type **Redirect** request at www. |
| A record **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** --> d21xyz | **d21xyz**.cloudfront.net --> 2. | 2. [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) public stores **assets** |

So now when I turn on ACLs I have to have 2 sets of ACLs??? Doubling the cost.

-

**2. Here** is the configuration of what I would expect as a setup based on my previous experience with on premise servers
but I cannot find any advice on this, nor can I find any other solid tutorials like the setup above making it a bit hard to know.

| Route53 | Cloudfront Dist | S3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A record **example.com** --> d1wxyz | **d1wxyz**.cloudfront.net --> 1. | 1. example.com public stores **assets** |
| CName record **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)** --> d1wxyz | d1wxyz.cloudfront.net (as above) | example.com public stores assets (as above) |

This way seems more logical to me 1 bucket, no redirect from the second bucket and 1 distribution with a simple A record and CNAME both pointing at the Base distribution.
then only 1 set of ACLs are required?

the first way works, but seems overly complex, but maybe there is a good reason?
the 2nd seems more logical as per other web server setups I have done. But maybe there are pitfalls?

**Which is the correct way?** (assuming a simple website with Base domain and www subdomain)

I hope I have explained this well enough.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS documentation outlines this for S3 [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html), and with CloudFront [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-cloudfront-walkthrough.html).

Short version, you set up Route53 to use an Alias record pointing at CloudFront for both the base domain and subdomain, rather than an A record CNAME.

You should use an Origin Access Identity to prevent direct access to S3, as you get 1TB of free data egress from CloudFront and only 100GB from S3 ([reference](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-free-tier-data-transfer-expansion-100-gb-from-regions-and-1-tb-from-amazon-cloudfront-per-month/)).

Comment: I did not setup 2 buckets as per the documentation, it started working just as I was about to try this.
I used my second approach with www as a CNAME and it works great, I will let it soak and see how it goes.
Only thing I added was the www as an alternate Alias to

Comment: There are often good reasons to follow the recommendations. From memory, alias record querys are free, which is one reason to use them.

Comment: The documentation does not refer to 2 distributions.
I think this is what I am struggling with.
surely either 1xCloudFront can redirect accordingly or rewrite like .htaccess
So I cannot see how it works without a second distribution.
But the docs do not advise a second one, and a second one seems redundant.

Comment: If you're talking about redirecting a www to the base domain, or vice versa, you can leave S3 to do the redirect. CloudFront can redirect http to https but can't do www -> base or vice versa, as far as I know, but I haven't used it in ages I've just reviewed it for AWS certifications.